# Ширина страницы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Нужно узнавать текущую ширину страницы и делать определённые действия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ширина страницы - понятие не вполне определённое.

```js
// Ширина окна браузера
console.log(window.innerWidth); 
//Ширина страницы (полный размер, вместе с бордерами  прокруткой)
console.log(document.body.offsetWidth); 
// Ширина страницы без учета прокрутки 
console.log(document.body.clientWidth);
// Ширина страницы + прокрутка 
console.log(document.body.scrollWidth);
```

```css
body{
width: 2500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще так

```
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
alert('Это похоже мобильное устройство');
}
```

Comment: А еще лучше вот так: `if (window.screen.availWidth < 768) ... `

Answer (score 0):

Jquery

```
width = $(window).width();
if(/* условие */){
....
}
```

При изменении размера окна снова проверяем:

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){

width = $(window).width();
if(/* условие */){
....
}

});
```

Для `CSS` можете использовать [Медиа-запросы](http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media)

Comment: Тот кто минусует мой ответ, может выскажет причину минусования ? или сказать нечего, минусуют просто так ?